# Populate checkbox from array

Tags: php

Hi I've data for year store as serialize like this

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"2011";i:1;s:4:"2013";}
```

and have a list of predefined year like this:

```
$current_year = date('Y');
for($year = 2011; $year < $current_year; $year++) 
{
 $year;
}
```

So, I want to populate a list of checkboxes like below:
[x] 2011
[ ] 2012
[x] 2013
...

If the year is not in the predefined year (in this case 2011,2012 and 2013), the year should be unchecked.

I've search but so far the nearest solution is not in PHP

Comment: `echo "<input type='checkbox' value='$year'".(in_array($year,$Array)?" checked":"")." />";` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. Check this.

```
<?php 
 $dat='a:2:{i:0;s:4:"2011";i:1;s:4:"2013";}';
 $data=unserialize($dat); 
 $current_year = date('Y');
for($year = 2011; $year <= $current_year; $year++) 
{
    if(in_array($year,$data))   {       $checked="CHECKED";     }   else { $checked=""; } ?>
    <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $year; ?>" name="year[]"  <?php echo $checked; ?> > <?php echo $year; ?> <br/>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: BTW, your solution was exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: Great Fadli. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

```
$years = unserialize($mysql_years);
$current_year = date('Y');
for ($year = 2011; $year < $current_year; $year++) {
    $checked = '';
    if (in_array($year, $years)) {
        $checked = ' checked';
    }
    echo "<input type=checkbox value=$year$checked>";
}
```