# Using PHP, Retrieve Array from MySQL Field and Use It to Fill Checkbox Group

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox, explode

**CONTEXT**

I am developing a profile creation form with a checkbox group that implodes and inserts the comma-separated array into a MySQL table ($profile_table).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" value="Foo" /> Foo<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" value="Bar" /> Bar<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" value="Baz" /> Baz<br />
                
$insert_array = implode(", ", $_POST['check_group']);
```

If all checkboxes are checked, the array looks like: "Foo, Bar, Baz"

```
$insert_profile_query = "INSERT INTO profile_table
(check_group_field)VALUES ('".$insert_array."')";   
$profile_query_qs = db_query($insert_profile_query);
```

The code above works.

I need an edit profile page where the checkbox group is pre-filled using the array that was created above and inserted in the MySQL $profile_table.

Using the "Foo" checkbox as an example, I believe the answer uses an in_array conditional and is something close to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" value="Foo"
<? $my_array = array(explode(", ", $profile_table['check_group_field'])); 
if (in_array("Foo", $my_array)) {echo 'checked="checked"';}?> /> Foo<br />
```

**QUESTION**

Specifically, what is the best function to get the array out of the MySQL $profile_table.check_group_field so I can use it in the in_array conditional as $my_array to pre-fill the checkboxes in the checkbox group? Do I need to explode the array first?

**EXAMPLE RESOURCES**

Here is an example of the many resources I am referencing; but, I am not finding the specific issue I need to address:

https://www.php.net/in_array
http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?577188-Retrieving-A-Checkbox-Array-from-MySql
[Populate checkbox from array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15756107/populate-checkbox-from-array)

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for confirming I was in the ballpark! I played around with the function more and by deduction found my error.

$my_array = array(explode(", ", $profile_table['check_group_field'])); is wrong.

Explode creates an array, so array(explode... is redundant.

I believe the statement should be:

$my_array = (explode(", ", $profile_table['check_group_field']));

Answer (score 2):

```
$x=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM DB");
while($y=mysql_fetch_array){ 
echo "<input type='checkbox' name=".$y." value='Foo' >";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the values of the checkboxes in an array and run through all of the options in a foreach and check if the value is in the array in a similar fashion to what you used.

```
$options=array('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz');
$my_array = array(explode(", ", $profile_table['check_group_field']));
foreach($options as $option){
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="check_group[]" value="'.$option.'" ';
    if(in_array($option, $my_array)){
        echo 'checked="checked"';
    }
    echo '/>';
}
```